# igoogle style page with content scraped from other pages

Tags: screen-scraping

I'm looking for an online homepage or Chrome extension that will display an iGoogle type home page but that lets me select content from other pages. In the same way AdBlock will allow me to select a div to block - I want to select a div to display on my home page - effectively screen-scraping.

Is there anything around that will let me do this?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you just gave away a multi-milion idea.